# Add buttons for free slots in week view

Tags: fullcalendar, timeslots

I would like to add buttons for weekly view in fullcalendar, as time slots and make them bookable slots.
I tried to add in Javascript Content Injection for Fullaclendar but I cant.

[image: here is an example of my thoughts]

Comment: Why not just use the time grid view? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-view . You can customise the slot size.

Comment: It's ok, but how and where can I add buttons like slots, which are bookable?

Comment: You don't need to. Let the user [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting) the timeslot they want. You could possibly use visual cues to show which areas are free, e.g. by using [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events), and then you can also use the constraint mechanisms (see my first link) to ensure the user can only select the available slots, and/or can only select a certain duration of time).